# My express mongoose populate not giving the result of other collection

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i have created two collection in mongoose like below
1.Category schema
        const categorySchema = new Schema({

```
                    name:{
                        type:String,
                        required:true
                    },
                    cat_type:{
                        type:String,
                        enum:['images','quotes','videos']
                    },
                    image:{
                        type:String
                    },
                    videoId:{
                        type:Number
                    }
    })


      const Category = mongoose.model('categories',categorySchema); 
      module.exports = Category;
```

2.Video Schema

```
        const videoSchema = new Schema({
                    videoId:{
                        type:String
                    },
                    title:{
                        type:String,
                        required:true
                    },
                    cat_id:{
                            type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                            ref:'categories'
                    },
                    description:{
                        type:String
                    },
                    url:{
                        type:String
                    },
                    publishedAt:{
                        type:String
                    }

           })

        const Video = mongoose.model('videos',videoSchema);
        module.exports = Video
```

And i am using the below query to get the video and the category details of the video

```
          Video.find({}).
          populate('categories')
          .exec(function(err, data){
          console.log(data);
          })
```

But i am just getting the result of video table only not the categories table, what i am doing wrong in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to populate the field **cat_id**, not categories. The field you put in populate should be the field that references the other schema, in this case that would be cat_id